# Calculation of labor, capital and productivity deviation

Tags: labor-economics, productivity, capital

In  Ohanian (2010): The Economic Crisis from a Neoclassical Perspective ( https://pubs.aeaweb.org/doi/pdfplus/10.1257/jep.24.4.45 ) I read about labor, capital and productivity deviation. I would like to calculate those numbers for the current economic situation (2018 - 2020+) but I don't understand how the calculation works. Can someone explain to me how those are calculated? Which data do I need?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The details are outlined in the original Business Cycle Accounting-paper by Chari et al. (2007) at https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1468-0262.2007.00768.x

A replication is at https://github.com/JohannesPfeifer/DSGE_mod/tree/master/Chari_et_al_2007